# How to add multiline header view in swift, cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa, tableview

I have a table, it has 3 columns Column A, Column B & Column C.
For Column B & Column C, it should have a header for the both column named Group.

How this can be achieved in Cocoa & Swift.

Basically how to achieve multiline header in cocoa & Swift.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You'd better google a tutorial how to use `UITableView`. `UITableView` has a `tableHeaderView` on the top and section **header** for each section:

for example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if groupBAndCSecontion {
        return "Group"
    }else{
        return "Not Group"
    }
}
```

I didn't do OSX before, but FYI:

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTableCellView *cell = nil;
        // get your row from your array of objects.
        // determine if it's a section heading or not.

    SomeClass *someObject = [self.myObjects objectAtIndex:row];

    if (someObject.isSectionHeading) {
        cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" owner:self];
        cell.textField.objectValue = someObject.headingName;
    } else {
        cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];
        cell.textField.objectValue = someObject.rowValue;
    }

    return cell;

}
```

And more: http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nstableview-sample-code/

Comment: We are using NSTableView and not UITableView. Kindly advice if it can be done for NSTableView

Comment: @WilliamHu Please use Swift code, the question has the "swift" tag. Thank you.